# Get Dropbox OAuth Token from Code via request.js Fails; Equivalent curl Works

Tags: javascript, oauth, request, http-post, dropbox-api

I'm trying to exchange my Dropbox oauth code for a token as per the [http api](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation) documentation.

When I perform the command with curl thusly:

```
curl https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/token \
-d code=<authorization code> \
-d grant_type=authorization_code \
-u <app key>:<app secret>
```

everything works fine, and I am returned my bearer token. Unfortunately, what
seems to be equivalent code written in node.js with the request module fails.

```
var request = require("request");
var config = require("./config.json");

request({
  url: "https://api.dropboxapi.com/1/oauth2/token",
  method: "POST",
  auth: {
    user: config.client_id,
    pass: config.client_secret
  },
  json: {
    code: config.code,
    grant_type: "authorization_code"
  } 
}, function(err, resp, body) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(body);
});
```

logs:

```
{ error_description: 'missing required field "grant_type"',
  error: 'invalid_request' }
```

[The docs](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation)
say that in the event of a 400 error (which this is), I have:

> Bad input parameter. Error message should indicate which one and why.

Though as can be seen from the above code, the `grant_type` *is* being
specified.

---

Notably the docs give a second option to authenticate, though this too fails,
albeit with a different message:

> ## Description (abridged)
>
> Calls to /oauth2/token need to be authenticated using the apps's key and secret. These can either be passed as POST parameters (see parameters below) or via HTTP basic authentication. If basic authentication is used, the app key should be provided as the username, and the app secret should be provided as the password.
>
> ## Params
>
> - `code` *String* The code acquired by directing users to /oauth2/authorize?response_type=code.
> - `grant_type` String The grant type, which must be `authorization_code`.
> - `client_id` *String* If credentials are passed in POST parameters, this parameter should be present and should be the app's key (found in the App Console).
> - `client_secret` *String* If credentials are passed in POST parameters, this parameter should be present and should be the app's secret.
> - `redirect_uri` *String* Only used to validate that it matches the original /oauth2/authorize, not used to redirect again.

My attempt at the alternate authentication procedure:

```
var request = require("request");
var config = require("./config.json");

request({
  url: "https://api.dropboxapi.com/1/oauth2/token",
  method: "POST",
  json: {
    code: config.code,
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    client_id: config.client_id,
    client_secret: config.client_secret
  } 
}, function(err, resp, body) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(body);
});
```

logs:

```
{ error_description: 'No auth function available for given request',
  error: 'invalid_request' }
```

In case the full response from dropbox for either of my two request attemps would be helpful [I posted it on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/YzqaFq38).

I am not including the `redirect_uri` as I did not use it as part of the code
flow. This is permitted as per the docs. In any case, I don't have any problems
when ommitting it in the `curl` command which *does* succeed.

Considering that my API call succeeds when sent through curl, I'm clearly doing
something wrong with my js request. What can I do to get the bearer token I
expect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like in your `curl` command, you're sending a form-encoded POST request (which is what OAuth uses), but in your Node.js code, you're sending a JSON-encoded request.

Try `form: { ... }` instead of `json: { ... }`.